# Which short-term UK visa is applicable for a remote independent contractor working outside of the UK for a UK company?

Tags: visas, uk, business-travel, working-visas

I have been working for a UK-based company as a remote independent contractor for the last 3 years. I want to do a short-term visit to the UK to meet the team and work from there for a few weeks. The company will reimburse me for my stay/travel expenses. Which visa do you think is applicable for this?

From what I can see from the *gov.uk* website, there are two kinds of visas that I may be eligible for:

- Standard Visitor visa
- Permitted Paid Engagement visa

Which one of the two do you think is the right category of visa for me?

Comment: What exactly does ‘work’ mean? Are all the activities you’re planning allowed under Visitor https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-visitor-permitted-activities  or  PPE rules https://www.gov.uk/permitted-paid-engagement-visa? See also https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1019544/Visit.pdf If you can work for them remotely from your country of residence, how will you convince the ECO that you wouldn’t overstay?

Comment: Cross site duplicate on Expatriates: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/22545/which-short-term-uk-visa-is-applicable-for-a-remote-independent-contractor-worki Please do not ask exact copies, you can ask different but related questions though. Mods can move questions if you had asked on the wrong site.

Comment: @Willeke thanks, I wasn't sure which was the correct place to ask this; I've now deleted the question from the expatriates SE.

Comment: @Traveller From the link you shared, my short-term visit activities would probably fall under "General Business Activities: attend interviews, meetings, conferences and seminars". But since I am working as an independent remote contractor for this UK company, I am a bit unsure if this is applicable to me?

Comment: The Rules say “ You cannot do paid or unpaid work for a UK company or as a self-employed person as a visitor.” I think you may fall foul of this *unless* you are **only** going to carry out the permitted activities as in the answer from @DJClayworth. If you will also be doing the same activities for the company while in the UK that you already do remotely, you will need a work visa, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

You want a [Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor/visit-on-business).

You are allowed to:

- attend interviews, meetings, conferences and seminars
- get work-related training if you’re employed overseas and the training is not available in your home country
- deliver training or share knowledge on internal projects with UK employees of the company you work for overseas

Meeting the team and exchanging information with them is covered by that. Do NOT say that you are going to "work there for a few weeks", either when applying or when you arrive. You are there to attend meetings with your colleagues, train them and receive training, plan and review work. You are not going to "work" according to the definition used by UK immigration.

Permitted Paid Engagement is for academics, artists and recognized experts in their field.

Comment: thanks for your answer. 

"You are there to attend meetings with your colleagues, train them and receive training, plan and review work"

Since I do not work for an overseas company, but a company in the UK itself, and that too as an independent contractor and not as an employee, is this still applicable for me?

Comment: I believe so. Check with a lawyer if you are unsure. In any case, the PPE visa is not appropriate.

Comment: You do not work for an UK company, cross border employment is practically impossible. You are a self employed contractor. Your employer is _not_ the UK company. They are your _client_. These are completely different things. As an aside: if you are not aware of this then you should immediately talk to an accountant who is well versed in these affairs because almost certainly you screwed up your taxes.